# I can't solve Error while running npm Start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I have an issue please. Each time I set up a react project, either with create react app or using webpack or whatever, I just get stuck at NPM start. It always returns an error. Please I am fed up with this. Can someone tell me what the issue might be?
But what bugs me the most is, I use Next.js, and each time I run Npm start on Nextjs dev server, it works fine... Please what might be the issue with my react app?

Here's the error:

```
C:\Users\Kelly\Desktop\My webpack react app>npm start

> webpackreactapp@1.0.0 start C:\Users\Kelly\Desktop\My webpack react app
> webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from C:\Users\Kelly\Desktop\My webpack react app
events.js:298
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)←[39m
←[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)←[39m
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)←[39m
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
←[90m    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)←[39m
←[90m    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)←[39m
←[90m    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)←[39m {
  errno: ←[33m-4058←[39m,
  code: ←[32m'ENOENT'←[39m,
  syscall: ←[32m'spawn cmd'←[39m,
  path: ←[32m'cmd'←[39m,
  spawnargs: [ ←[32m'/c'←[39m, ←[32m'start'←[39m, ←[32m'""'←[39m, ←[32m'/b'←[39m, ←[32m'http://localhost:8080/'←[39m ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webpackreactapp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webpackreactapp@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Kelly\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-04-07T07_23_56_199Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Run the following command inside your terminal: `BROWSER=none npm start`

Comment: Thanks for replying Zeeshan. But it says 'BROWSER' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: On which operating system are you running this app?

Comment: Windows 7 operating system

Comment: Try this command `set BROWSER=none&&npm start`

Comment: Unfortunately it still brought that same issue, I think it's that same error:

Comment: The npm ERR issue. I really don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Hi Zeeshan. Can you not help out with this issue? It really is delaying my projects. I need help please.

Comment: Try with the following command `npm run start BROWSER=none`

Comment: Or first run this command
`$env: BROWSER="none"`
then
`npm run start`

Comment: Oh okay. Let me try that. thank you

Comment: First, the terminal says $env is not recognized as an internal or external command, then I  included "set" just like you said with the first command, then I ran "npm run start", but it still didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Just to be sure Zeeshan, is it a browser issue?

Comment: I think so because your app is trying to open url in browser but it is not getting the access to open the url

Comment: Hmm... Okay thanks. Please I will be glad to get any possible solutions to this if you find any.

Answer (score 1):

About this question I posted here earlier, I finally found a solution to it. And I hope it would help someone. I think it's probably due to my computer's OS, the fact is I still don't know the reason my NPM start didn't work, but I found out that it was because my "react-scripts" version, which can be found in your package.json, was 3.4.1, which I think is the latest. I tried downloading the lower versions up till 2.1.8, then it worked at version 2.1.8. Though that version is way outdated, and it's probably not recommended that anyone use it, but if you still are stuck like I was, then you should try it, until you find a better solution.

Just write these commands:

npx create-react-app my-app

cd my-app

npm i --save-dev react-scripts@2.1.8

npm start

That should work and help you get your app on board. 
I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have added insufficient paths in your Environmental variables.

First you can do is close the vs code,

Go to the properties of My Pc,

Click on Advanced Settings,

click on Environmental Variables,

from there you can add path clicking the path variables in the table. Add a new line to the path and copy paste the path of your system 32,

C:\Windows\System32

hope this solution works in your case

(I've been trying to fix this problem for so long this is the only solution i found that worked)

Answer (score 0):

Have you restored the npm packages?
In the terminal, run: 
`npm install`

Comment: Alright Typeset.. Should I run npm start afterwards?

Comment: npm install will install any dependencies (that is, if they were missing). Then npm start should work

Comment: Also in what situation can I run npm run dev? Cuz I do that often using next.js, and it works fine. Doing it with react always tells me that there's no dev script in my package.json file...

Comment: npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.12: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"})... I got this line of warning after running npm install. Does it affect anything? Cuz npm start still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure. In your `package.json` file under `scripts` you will see the available options.

Comment: "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"

This is what I have under scripts in my package.json file. Because I am using webpack

Comment: It looks like I can't solve this issue here or for now, is it recommended that I use react cdn links instead?

Answer (score 0):

i was also facing this same issue . after spending some time i just simply install the node.js most user  version . and now issue is fixed . before it was installed latest version of node js.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).